# Dynamically generated og:image that can be viewed by Discord

Tags: png, meta

So I'm trying to create a dynamic user profile og:image. So when a users profile is linked it will display there avatar and name. I've successfully created the image using [Image Processing](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and with Get Requests I can piece the user's data together to create the image. The end URL looks like this, `domain.com/profile/image.php?name=jim&avitar=face.png` but I've now worked out that most messaging platforms such as Discord appear to require a solid image such as .png or .jpg
So my question is how I can make this work... 
 Thanks in advance.

**Note that adding .png or .jpg to the end of the link didn't work xD**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I worked out the issue. I was playing around with some other meta tags and found `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` when I set these the image was displayed correctly.